# the symbol $\lhd$ in the trees context

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-set-theory, notation, trees, forcing

In the second line of the claim $4.2$ from Shelah's book Proper&Improper forcing, please what is $\lhd$ ?
I cannot find the definition of this order in previous sections of the book.

I believe that this is an initial segment of a sequence is that correct ?
[image]

Comment: What is "Shelah's P&I forcing"?

Comment: @Théophile See my edit above.

Comment: That partial order is probably defined in an earlier section. Often there's a notation index in the end of a math book. Check if there's one in this book.

Comment: @md2perpe There's no notation index in his book.

Comment: Although the symbol $\lhd$ for the tree order is never actually used, it is clear from the proof of $\mathbf{4.2}$ that it is simply strict inclusion: the nodes of the tree are functions from finite ordinals to $2$, and if $\sigma$ and $\tau$ are nodes, then $\sigma\lhd\tau$ iff $\sigma\subsetneqq\tau$. Since $\sigma$ and $\tau$ are finite sequences, this amounts, as you suspected, to saying that $\sigma$ is a proper initial segment of $\tau$.